# Why is my center always off in my projection with different scales

Tags: d3.js

```
const projection: GeoProjection = geoMercator();
projection.center([-98.5795, 39.8283]).scale(props.width / 2);
const path = geoPath().projection(projection);
```

I'm currently using a mercator projection in which i want to center on the US geographical center which is [-98.5795, 39.8283] and it is perfectly centered when my browser is maximized, however when i'm the browser is smaller say at a width of 800px, the projection is fully off center and includes much more of alaska. How do i get it so that it is always in the cneter?

here are some screenshot references

https://i.stack.imgur.com/yluhv.jpg

Comment: found the problem. If `translate(x,y)` is not defined on projection, the default translation is (960, 500)

Comment: The default translation should be 480,250 - anticipating map dimensions of 960, 500.